# ksh: remove last extension from a multiple extension filename

Tags: file, ksh

I have a filename in the format dir1/dir2/filename.txt.org and I like to rename this to dir1/dir2/filename.txt   . how can this be done. I tried 'cut' with '.' separator but it also removes .txt

Answer (score 0):

You can try korn shell variable expansion formats, instead of using a subprocess (e.g. cut) . This can be much faster.

example:

```
var1=dir1/dir2/filename.txt.org
var2=${var1%.*}
```

If you now `print $var2` its value will be `dir1/dir2/filename.txt`

The % tells it to delete the smallest matching rightmost match for `.*`  (which means anything following the rightmost period character).

`${variable%pattern}` - return the value of `variable` without the smallest ending portion that matches `pattern`.

Other variable expansion formats are available, it is worthwhile to study the docs.

Comment: how do we use ksh for the subshell?

Comment: instead of `sh -c` use `ksh -c`